# Template arguments passed in a function pointer declaration

Tags: templates, function-pointers

Maybe its too simple in this forum. but cant get through this. Please let me know what is the problem with the following declaration.

```
class Temp
{
public :
        template<class T>
        typedef void (*set_data)(T* data) ;
};
```

Gives me following error
template declaration of `typedef'

Comment: why cant i see template<class T> in the above edit?

Answer (score 0):

typedefs cannot be templated. You use alias templates for that

```
template<typename T>
using set_data = void(*)(T*);
```